Our website is on Kirby CMS but if we use CiviCRM on Drupal, Joomal or Wordpress is it still possible to embed CiviCRM forms on our website?
We're interested in using CiviCRM for our org. But our website is built with kirby CMS. I understand CiviCRM must  sit on Wordpress, Joomal or Drupal. Would we have problems embedding forms like email subscription and volunteer sign up forms on our website? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Another option to consider (in the future) might be the new/coming 'standalone' version of civi but it is very bleeding edge i believe at the moment.

Unfortunately, it isn't straightforward to embed CiviCRM forms on an external site. The simplest option would be to host the forms on the CiviCRM site and link to them from your main website.
Other options include:

creating a form on your website and using the CiviCRM API
using an iframe
using the Inlay extension
using the Form Processor extension

None are completely straightforward and will probably require some development work.

You can use CiviCRM Webform integrations with Drupal. Also there are some extensions/plugins available for other CMS.
